# How do I add text-based units like "lbs" floated to right inside of an input element (or outside of it)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to insert units inside an input element?  Inside the `<input>` element is preferred, but outside is acceptable.

[image]

Comment: Please add all relevant HTML and CSS that you currently have to the question.

Comment: You could add the unit symbol, "ft" for example, in the input field but then it would be part of the value, not what you want.  Alternatively, you could overlay the input field over an element that contains the symbol, which requires extra markup but it can do the job.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use something like this.

Outside box:

```
<input></input><span style="margin-left:10px;">lb</span>
```

Inside box:

```
<input style="padding-right:20px; text-align:right;" value="50"></input><span style="margin-left:-20px;">lb</span>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntfLv7sn/)

Comment: I vote for your answer. Using margin-left is better in this case indeed.

Answer (score 12):

You can make use of bootstrap input-group component.

**Note**: The example below uses bootstrap 4 classes

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="number" class="form-control">
   <div class="input-group-append">
       <span class="input-group-text"> m </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result below:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want the units to show up right beside the number, you can try this trick (https://jsfiddle.net/ccallendar/5f8wzc3t/24/). The input value is rendered in a div that is positioned on top of the input, with the value part hidden. That way the units are positioned correctly. Just make sure to use the identical styles (font sizes, colors, padding etc).

[image: Input with units]

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const hiddenValue = document.getElementById("hiddenValue");
const unitsValue = document.getElementById("unitsValue");
input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  hiddenValue.innerHTML = input.value;
  // Only show units when there is a value?
  // unitsValue.innerHTML = (input.value.length > 0 ? " km" : "");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
}

#input {
  border: 2px solid #fee400;
  background-color: #373637;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 10px;
  color: white;
}

.units {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  
  /* Match input styles */
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: normal;
  
  /* includes border width */
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 12px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#unitsValue {
  /* Support spaces */
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="input"type="number" value="12" />
  <div class="units">
    <span class="invisible" id="hiddenValue">12</span>
    <span class="units-value" id="unitsValue"> km</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do this by nudging an extra element (like a span) over the input using `position: relative` and `left: -20px`.

Then some `padding-right` on the input element to ensure that the user's input wont overlap on the new element.

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/peg3mdsg/1/

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `bootstrap`, you can use `input-groups` component and override some of the `bootstrap` styling :

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group unity-input">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter unity value" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" /> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
            lbs
        </span>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-group {
    top:40px;
    width:auto;
}
.unity-input .form-control {
    border-right:0!important;
}
.unity-input .input-group-addon {
    background:white!important;
    border-left:none!important;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zae4049)

Comment: @dkoss This is Bootstrap 3.3.4

Answer (score 1):

Here: (numbers are arbitrary and you can play around with those, what's important is to float the input and the negative margin on the span holding the measurement unit)

CSS:

```
#form>span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}
#form>input {
    padding: 5px 16px 5px 5px;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="form">
    <span class="units">lb</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" />
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pjohj19w/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem I have found with all of the previous answers is that, if you change the length of the units (for example, "€/month" instead of "lb") the `<span>` element won't be correctly aligned.

I found a better answer in another post, and it's really simple:

Html

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input></input>
  <span class="units">lb</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
.units {
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px (or the px that fit with your design);
}
```

This way, you can even put a long unit such as "€/month" and it will still be correctly positioned.

Answer (score 0):

using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/):

```
            <label for="idinput">LABEL</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="idinput" type="text" pattern="(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)" [(ngModel)]="input"/>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">m3/s</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

The only thing you can try with strictly css and html is placeholder and text align left. with jquery you could you the .addClass command.

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaHurlburt/34nzt2d1/1/

```
input {
    text-align:right;
}
```